# How to convert Node.js command line app to single executable?

Tags: node.js, windows, command, node-commander

I built simple command line application using `commander.js` for Node.js platform.
Now I want to compile it to simple `exe` file, Which I can execute directly.

> Means I want single executable file for complete application

This is my application structure

```
APP_ROOT
  | - package.json
  | - node_modules
  | - node_modules/.bin/myapp.bat
  | - node_modules/myapp/bin/myapp
  | - node_modules/myapp/bin/myapp-action1
  | - node_modules/myapp/bin/myapp-action2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- This is, How i packages my node.js command line app to single executable
- Install `pkg` module using `npm i -g pkg`
- This is my `package.json` File

json

```
{
  "name": "my-app-exe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Myapp-Cli tool as executable",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "myapp",
    "cli",
    "exe"
  ],
  "author": "Shisht",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "myapp": "1.0.0"
  },
  "bin": "node_modules/myapp-cli/bin/cli",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": "node_modules/**/*"
  },
  "help": "pkg . --target host --output myapp-1.0.0-x64.exe --debug"
}
```

- Command used to package `myapp` to `myapp.exe`

  `pkg . --target host --output myapp-1.0.0-x64.exe --debug`

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to run a Node application without some kind of Node runtime to run it *on* - therefore, if you wish to distribute your program as a standalone `.exe`, you will have to bundle Node itself into said executable as well as your code. There are various tools that will do this for you, such as [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/).

Comment: Size don't matter, Yes I have to embed `node.exe` into packaged executable, But how can i? Do you know about `babel` command line tool? Can you please post working example to package it as single executable?

Comment: `EncloseJS` failed to install on `Windows` because failed to download resource from `https://enclosejs.s3.amazonaws.com/enclose-v0.12.15-win32-5c54091.exe.sha256`

Comment: @sspsingh: Babel is irrelevant here - it'll compile your JavaScript to work with older versions of the browser/Node, but it has no impact on how you'd package it. That error looks like an issue with your network.

Comment: My node.js shell app is just like `babel` or any other package, which can be used on shell. So i you can try with babel, I will fix it to work with my app, that's why i asked?

Comment: @sspsingh: Oh, I see what you mean! There's [examples of how to package various existing command line tools in the EncloseJS GitHub](https://github.com/igorklopov/enclose/tree/master/examples) - i'd recommend using those as a starting point.